# Asterisk API SDP Handling

Tags: sip, asterisk, rtp, sdp

I have two SIP clients ( "A" and "B" ) connected to asterisk on generic bridge mode.

"A"'s video is playing back on "B" but "B"'s video is **NOT** playing back on "A". I triple checked with wireshark that the media ( audio / video ) 
is arriving at "A"'s ip address. Audio is working well on both sides.

My best guess is that this issue is related to asterisk's internal SDP handling.

So, lets delve into the problem.

**"A" sends the followind INVITE:**

```
INVITE sip:700@192.168.7.227 SIP/2.0  
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.7.225:10074;branch=z9hG4bK-224696310;rport  
From: "danflu-portsip"<sip:danflu-portsip@192.168.7.227>;tag=87652133  
To: <sip:700@192.168.7.227>  
Contact: <sip:danflu-portsip@192.168.7.225:10074;transport=udp>;  
Call-ID: YTc0NDRjNDYtMWRhMS01MzE2LWVlNDEtYmV  
CSeq: 1354707857 INVITE  
Content-Type: application/sdp  
Content-Length: 447  
Max-Forwards: 70  
Authorization: Digest username="danflu-portsip",realm="asterisk",nonce="5ac40c6d",uri="sip:700@192.168.7.227",response="fae8a78ba97    2f6cb0c76846d76f13786",algorithm=MD5
User-Agent: PortSIP SDK for IOS
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, REGISTER, SUBSCRIBE, INFO
P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:danflu-portsip@192.168.7.227>
Supported: 100rel

v=0  
o=portsip 2013 678901 IN IP4 192.168.7.225  
s=-  
c=IN IP4 192.168.7.225  
t=0 0  
m=audio 20554 RTP/AVP 8 0 97 18  
a=ptime:20  
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000  
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000  
a=rtpmap:97 SPEEX/8000  
a=rtpmap:18 g729/8000  
a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes  
a=sendrecv  
a=ssrc:258325709 cname:258325709  
m=video 29350 RTP/AVP 104  
a=rtpmap:104 H264/90000  
a=fmtp:104 profile-level-id=42801E; packetization-mode=1  
a=sendrecv  
a=ssrc:1956389748 cname:1956389748
```

**and receives a "200 OK" message from Asterisk:**

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK  
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.7.225:10010;branch=z9hG4bK-282879312 received=192.168.7.225;      
rport=10010  
From: "danflu-portsip"<sip:danflu-portsip@192.168.7.227>;tag=539964865  
To: <sip:9993@192.168.7.227>;tag=as1b6086b5  
Call-ID: OTE4MjM3NzUtMDIzNy1mNTM1LWM3MzYtOGZ  
CSeq: 1074035624 INVITE  
Server: Asterisk PBX SVN-branch-1.8-r402287M  
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH  
Supported: replaces, timer  
Contact: <sip:9993@192.168.7.227:5060>  
Content-Type: application/sdp  
Content-Length: 375  

v=0  
o=root 826339596 826339596 IN IP4 192.168.7.227  
s=Asterisk PBX SVN-branch-1.8-r402287M  
c=IN IP4 192.168.7.227  
b=CT:384  
t=0 0  
m=audio 9540 RTP/AVP 8 0 101  
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000  
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000  
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000  
a=fmtp:101 0-16  
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -  
a=ptime:20  
a=sendrecv  
m=video 7450 RTP/AVP 104  
a=rtpmap:104 H264/90000  
a=sendrecv
```

Note that the lines:

> a=fmtp:104 profile-level-id=42801E; packetization-mode=1

and

> a=ssrc:1956389748 cname:1956389748

simply disappeared in the response and I really think thats the reason the video is not working.

So, my question:

**What API can I use to customize this behavior, so the lines above are not removed when Asterisk handles the SDP from both sides ?
If there is not an official API where could I look in the code for this ? So I could maybe write a patch for my specific situation ?**

I looked in chan_sip.c and there is a function:

> static int process_sdp(struct sip_pvt *p, struct sip_request *req, int t38action)

But I'm not sure if this SDP handling ( removing lines and the like ) is perfomed by asterisk core or by the sip channel driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk video is very strange thing. Becuase asterisk not do transcoding for video codecs/streams.

Only really working mode - all video codecs are turned off and only single codec turned on on all peers.

For more info see [Asterisk Video on voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+video)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if this SDP "filtering" is performed by Asterisk "core" or only by the SIP channel driver ?

Comment: core not know anything about SDP. There are no filtering, there are codecs. Transcoding for video is not implemented. Preference implemented, but not work realible. Re-invites(start of video after start of sound) implemented,but depend of softphones/hardphones on both sides.

Comment: So who remove the SDP lines is the SIP channel driver (chan_sip.c), right ? Basically I'll need to understand its inner workings and patch it there. Another possibility would be implementing a SIP proxy between the sip device and asterisk and filter all the data in the proxy itself. Do you have any other ideas, suggestions ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: It create NEW invite. Never route existing. Asterisk will not work as sip proxy. If you need sip proxy, use kamailio.